# Node API - Date Time params

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have an endpoint where I pass date and time as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

```
#passing datetime via URL 2018-04-10%2020:00:00
moment.format()
```

I would like to add miliseconds so I added

```
#passing datetime via URL 2018-04-10%2020:00:00:1000
date.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')

#DB datetime format "2017-11-28 08:39:43.503"
```

Now I get this message

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: it's definitely a date format issue

Comment: I know you already figured out the problem. But the error message looks like an error that is send by a database when you try to store a value in the format `2018-04-10 20:00:00:1000` and not by moment or node.

Answer (score 1):

Dang it. The format was off by a period.

Should've been

```
#passing datetime via URL 2018-04-10%2020:00:00.1000
date.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS')

#DB datetime format "2017-11-28 08:39:43.503"
```